# Riesz Representation Theorem Positivity Question

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

In $\mathbb{R}^S$, where $S < \infty$, if there is a linear functional such that $F(x) = 0$, $\forall x \in M$ and $F(y) > 0$, $\forall k \in K$ where $K$ and $M$ are linear subspaces, then can I assert that there is a strictly positive vector $\phi$ such that:

$$
F(z) = <x,\phi>, \forall z \in \mathbb{R}^S
$$

I suppose this is an application of Riesz Representation Theorem, I am unsure about the positivity part.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B = \{e_{1}, \ldots, e_{S} \}$ an orthonormal base for $\mathbb{R}^{S}$ and let $ \{e_{r_{1}}, \ldots, e_{r_{n}} \} \subset B$ an base ortonormal for $M$, respectively. Let's define $F_{K}: K \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $x \longmapsto F_{K}(x) = F(x)$ then $F_{K}(x) > 0$ for all $x\in K -\{0\}$.

On the other hand, $K$ is an vectorial space with inner product (the canonical inner product in $\mathbb{R}^{S}$) then for the Riesz representation theorem there is a vector $w\in K$ such that $F_{K}(x) = <x, w>$. Note that $<w, w > = F_{K}(w) >0$, i. e. $w$ strictly positive.

Now, if $y \in (\mathbb{R}^{S} - K)$ then $F(y) = <y, w> = 0$, in particular, $0 = F(y) = <y, w>$ for all $y\in M$.

Comment: I didn't follow why $w$ is strictly positive from $<w,w> > 0$.

Comment: Bescause $w \in K$ and F is strictly positive for all non-zero vector in $K$

Comment: True, missed that!